# Как организовать разделение ресурсов между потоками?

Tags: python, django, многопоточность, асинхронность, очередь

У меня есть модель Community, которая содержит ForeignKey поле app, которое, в свою очередь, просто хранит access token.

```
class Community(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey("VkApp")
    domen = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    @property
    def api(self):
        if self.app:
            access_token = self.app.access_token
        else:
            access_token = ""
        return PublicApiCommands(access_token=access_token, domen=self.domen)

    def get_posts(self, count):
        return self.api.get_post_list(count)


class VkApp(models.Model):
   access_token = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Метод `get_posts` обращается к `api` property, и возвращает объект класса `PublicApiCommands`, который, является оберткой вокруг vk api: внутри него вызываются `request.get('api.vk.com/bla?bla=bla')`

Теперь я хочу сделать app не `ForeignKey`, а `ManyToManyField`, чтобы для управления одним и тем же `Community` можно было использовать несколько разных access token-ов. Причем, у разных `Community` наборы токенов могут либо полностью совпадать, либо быть полностью различными.

Далее для всех `Community.objects.all()` вызывается по celery task-у, в котором вызывается `community.get_posts()`. Как же теперь сделать так, чтобы access_token при этом выбирался из доступных для данного community и при этом свободных в данный момент?

Предлагали использовать `Queue`, но я пока не могу понять, где производить инициализацию, где делать `get` и `put`.

Голова взрывается: впервые, наверное, встретился со столь для себя сложной задачей. Может быть нужно что-то почитать для начала? Буду рад любым советам. Спасибо!